# cannot read properties of undefined 'clientwidth' after jquery upgrade and migration

Tags: jquery, migration, typeerror, upgrade

I have jquery 2.4.1 on a website and need to update it to 3.5.0 (or the latest)
I have successfully updated in one file (and works in the page) but I need to also update in another file, the second file affects bar graphs in the website generated by HighChart.

I comment out the outdated jquery and paste the upgrade and migration directly below (please see image)

[jQuery update and script added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkjNB.png)

[Error message on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKIaH.png)

I am wondering If I am supposed to keep the outdated jquery? or download the update jquery and add it to a folder? Can someone please advise me? I am new too this.

Comment: you can delete the outdated library, once all references to it are removed. looking at your actual error, can you share `scripts.js line 55` ? Or the entire block / function that is going on around that part of your file?

Comment: plotOptions: {
bar: {
dataLabels: {
enabled: !0,
useHTML: !0,
formatter: function () {
if (0 === this.point.y) {
var e = this.series._i,
t = n.context.clientWidth / 2 - 69;
l.series[0];
if (l.series[e].data[0] < 0) {
4.13 * this.total;
return '<img style="max-width:none; width: 10px; height: 10px; margin-right: ' + t + 'px" src="' + l.zeroImage + '"/>'
}
return '<img style="max-width:none; width: 10px; height: 10px; margin-left: 20px" src="' + l.zeroImage + '"/>'
}
}
}
},

Comment: Thank you Mike, I pasted the block but it looks bad. The outdated jquery is referenced in 3 files and is used through out the website. I had commented it out and added the jquery update and migration...the charts still do not show up.